# do IAPs need to be reviewed for external Testflight beta

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm developing an iOS app with a 'Full Version' in-app purchase.
Internal TestFlight beta testing has been done successfully - neither the app nor the IAP were required to be submitted for review.

I've now submitted for review a new build for external TestFlight beta-testers  and it's status is 'Waiting for Beta App Review.'

Am I right in thinking that the IAP still DOES NOT need to be submitted for review and that only app versions submitted to the App Store need their IAPs submitted for review first?

I don't want to wait for 2 days only to find out I should have reviewed the IAP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Itunes Connect review policy. Please ask your question on Apple's Developer Forums.

Comment: SO should allow questions like these here. While it's not programming, it's very relevant to programmers. This question/answer actually made a difference to me.

Comment: Closing this question was stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app has now been approved for external beta testing.
 Therefore in-app purchases do not need to be sent for review when submitting a build for external beta testing.